Updating the header inside the middleware after using NextAuth
I am using Nextjs version 14 and I have placed the Middleware file inside src folder. I also use NextAuth for authorization, which works properly. But when I want to modify the headers inside middleware file(to run on the client server side), nothing changes and the changed headers is not taken on the backend side. However, if I put the changed headers value inside Fetch, it will be received on the backend side, but it couldn't be rendered statically because it used headers.
    import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "../auth.config";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from "./helper/authentication";

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};

const bypassAuth = ["/login", "/register"];

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (!bypassAuth.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    const username: string | null | undefined = await getToken();

    if (!username) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
    }
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
    requestHeaders.set("Authorization", username);
    requestHeaders.set("Content-Type", username);
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    response.headers.set("Authorization", username);
    response.headers.set("xxx", "123");

    response.headers.append("Authorization", username);
    return response;
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

and when using customFetch for all services and losing static rendering
import { auth } from "../../auth";

async function getToken() {
  const session = await auth();
  const username = session?.user?.name;
  return username;
}

export const customFetch = async (url: any, options?: any) => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const { signal } = controller;
  let username: string | null | undefined = await getToken();
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    // Add any other headers you want to include in every fetch call
    Authorization: username,
  };

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    ...options,
    signal,
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      ...options?.headers,
    },
  });
  return response;
};

